# Finding the average of time series data with lots of Site IDs

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the following format;

```
Site ID     Timestamp          Variable 1    Variable 2   Variable 3
fisiak      2022-04-03 10:15   1.4           1.00         3.75
fisiak      2022-04-03 10:30   9.4           0.10         8.75
fisiak      2022-04-03 10:45   11.4          0.00         3.55
irm4hd      2022-04-03 10:15   45.4          0.00         3.25
irm4hd      2022-04-03 10:30   9.4           0.10         8.25
irm4hd      2022-04-03 10:45   11.4          0.60         2.55
```

And I want to end up with something in this format;

```
Timestamp         Mean(Variable 1) Mean(Variable 2) Mean(Variable 3)
2022-04-03 10:15               1.4            1.00              3.75
2022-04-03 10:30               9.4            0.10              8.75
2022-04-03 10:45              11.4            0.00              3.55
```

I am having some trouble adding multiple Data Frames together. Currently I am looping through all site IDs and masking each sites separately with `.loc[:,'siteId']==site` and then trying to add all the dfs together.

I think I am over complicating things...

Comment: Although the numbers don't match, it looks like you could want to group per Timestamp: `df.groupby('Timestamp')[['Variable 1', 'Variable 2', 'Variable 3']].mean().add_prefix('Mean_')`

Comment: or, as your output suggest, if you want to split by group: `{k:g, for k,g in df.groupby('Site ID')}`